# Using Ember (cli) how do I get an acceptance test to wait for a promise?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I currently have a model that has a `findResults` function that returns a promise that is wrapping a Google Places library to fetch results for auto-completion. To use this in my UI, I setup a PromiseMixin controller. I instruct the controller to watch the `searchText` value, and when that changes I update the controller's promise value to be the promise returned by the `findResults` function, but with the new value from `searchText`. This works nicely when I'm playing with the app in the browser, however when I run my acceptance tests the test seems to finish before the promise is returned and therefore the tests fail. I'll include the relevant files below.

I'm not sure how to tell Ember to wait for the promise to resolve during testing.

**app/services/google-autocomplete-location.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";

var googleAutocompleteLocation = Ember.Object.extend({
  placeId: null,
  description: null
});

googleAutocompleteLocation.reopenClass({
  findResults: function(query) {
    var self = this;
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

      return autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({ input: query },
        function(predictions, status) {
          if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            Ember.run(null, reject, status);
          }
          else {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, self._decorateGoogleResults(predictions));
          }
        });
    });

    return promise;
  },

  _decorateGoogleResults: function(predictions) {
    var locations = [];

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      locations.push(
        googleAutocompleteLocation.create({
          placeId: prediction.place_id,
          description: prediction.description
        })
      );
    });


    return locations;
   }
});

export default googleAutocompleteLocation;
```

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";
import GoogleLocation from "../services/google-location";
import GoogleAutocompleteLocation from '../services/google-autocomplete-location';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin, {
  searchText: '',
  map: null,
  mapUrl: null,

  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      return this.transitionToRoute('entries.new');
    }
  },

  highlightedResult: function() {
    if (this.get('model').length) {
      return this.get('model')[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }.property('model'),

  setMap: (function() {
    if (this.get('highlightedResult') === null) {
      return this.set('map', null);
    } else {
      if (this.get('map') === null) {
        return this.set('map', GoogleLocation.create({
          mapContainer: Ember.$('.maps-info'),
          placeId: this.get('highlightedResult').placeId
        }));
      } else {
        return this.get('map').set('placeId', this.get('highlightedResult').placeId);
      }
    }
  }).observes('highlightedResult'),

  searchTextChanged: (function() {
    if (this.get('searchText').length) {
      this.set('promise',
        GoogleAutocompleteLocation.findResults(this.get('searchText')));
      console.log(this.get('promise'));
    } else {
      this.set('model', []);
    }
  }).observes('searchText')
});
```

**tests/acceptance/create-new-entry-test.js**

```
test('finding a location', function() {
  expect(1);
  visit('/');
  click('.location-input input');
  fillIn('.location-input input', "Los Angeles, CA");

  andThen(function() {
    var searchResult = find('.search-results ul li:first a').text();

    equal(searchResult, 'Los Angeles, CA, United States');
  });
});
```

Comment: I've opened an issue on this ember testing behavior here, feel free to chime in:  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10578

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to go about this is likely to register your own async test helper. I've prepared a JSBin with a simulation of your code and a solution here: http://jsbin.com/ziceratana/3/edit?html,js,output

The code used to create the helper is this:

```
Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper('waitForControllerWithPromise', function(app, controllerName) {
  return new Ember.Test.promise(function(resolve) {

    // inform the test framework that there is an async operation in progress,
    // so it shouldn't consider the test complete
    Ember.Test.adapter.asyncStart();

    // get a handle to the promise we want to wait on
    var controller = app.__container__.lookup('controller:' + controllerName);
    var promise = controller.get('promise');

    promise.then(function(){

      // wait until the afterRender queue to resolve this promise,
      // to give any side effects of the promise resolving a chance to
      // occur and settle
      Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', null, resolve);

      // inform the test framework that this async operation is complete
      Ember.Test.adapter.asyncEnd();
    });
  });
});
```

And it would be used like so:

```
test('visiting / and searching', function() {
  expect(1);
  visit('/');
  click('.location-input input');
  fillIn('.location-input input', "Los Angeles, CA");
  waitForControllerWithPromise('index'); // <-- simple & elegant!
  andThen(function(){
    var searchResult = find('.search-results ul li:first').text();
    equal(searchResult, 'Los Angeles, CA, United States');
  });
});
```

In ember-testing, an async-helper will automatically wait on previous promises and subsequent async helpers will wait on it when the test is executed. For excellent background on this, see Cory Forsyth's [Demystifying Async Testing](http://coryforsyth.com/2014/07/10/demystifing-ember-async-testing/)

Comment: It seems unfortunate to me to add code to the application only to satisfy tests. Is this because it’s an interaction with an external service?

Despite my discomfort, it did fix intermittent race condition failures in my tests, so thanks.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how this would work with a component?

Comment: @BuckDoyle ember-testing knows about many async things in Ember apps (items scheduled on the run loop, ajax operations and route transitions, for example), but when you are doing something in your app outside what ember-testing knows about (as in this question), you must figure out some approach to wait for that async action in your tests. Re: your component question, I would need more background to answer that question.

Comment: I need to look more into ember-testing because I’m not using an external service, it’s an Ember Data `.save()`, so I must be doing something wrong. Re components, I’m realising my current setup is a violation of “data down, actions up”, so once I address that I can use the same controller solution. But once controllers disappear…?! Thanks for your response!

Comment: Thanks so much for this workaround and explanation, Luke!  I was pretty frustrated to discover this behavior, and even filed an issue with ember about it.  Would you mind chiming in there?  Do you think this is an issue, or do you see this as a reasonable behavior?  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10578

Answer (score 10):

I'm new to this stuff and have been having similar difficulties today. I found that `andThen` will only wait for promises created using Ember Test promises,

```
var promise = Ember.Test.promise(function (resolve, reject) {...});
```

and not those where the promise is instantiated directly, i.e.

```
var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {...});
```

`Ember.Test.promise` returns a `new Ember.RSVP.Promise`, but also makes the step of setting `Ember.Test.lastPromise` to the promise instance before returning it. Maybe the answer here is for you to set `Ember.Test.lastPromise` to the promise you're waiting on?

Incidentally I also had to use `stop()` and `start()` in my case to prevent the test exiting before the second assert was called. I also needed to wrap the second assert in a `run.next` call to give the properties/DOM a chance to update:

```
test('shows content when unresolved promise resolves true', function() {
  expect(2);

  var resolveTestPromise;
  var testPromise = Ember.Test.promise(function (resolve) {
    resolveTestPromise = resolve;
  });

  // creates the component instance, stubbing the security service and template properties
  var component = this.subject({
    securityService: CreateMockSecurityService(testPromise),
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div id="if-may-test-div" />')
  });

  // appends the component to the page
  var $component = this.append();

  // our div shouldn't be visible yet
  equal($component.find('div#if-may-test-div').length, 0);

  stop();
  Ember.run.later(null, function () {resolveTestPromise(true);}, 1000);

  andThen(function () {
    Ember.run.next(function () {
      // div should be visible now
      equal($component.find('div#if-may-test-div').length, 1);
      start();
    });
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `Ember.Test.promise` did it with `stop()` and `start()`. I don't recall seeing that in the testing documentation at all and didn't even know it existed. So glad you pointed that out. Big help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem in [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) but have you tried to `stop()` and `start()`. In your case:

```
test('finding a location', function() {
  expect(1);
  stop();
  visit('/')
   .click('.location-input input')
   .fillIn('.location-input input', "Los Angeles, CA")
   .then(function() {
     var searchResult = find('.search-results ul li:first a').text();
     equal(searchResult, 'Los Angeles, CA, United States');
     start();
   });
});
```

Comment: I've just tried `start()` and `stop()`, but no luck. If I wrap my assertions in a setTimeout method with `stop()` and `start()` it will work, however if I give it enough time. I figured that if I call Ember.run in my promises Ember's test helpers would wait for the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're waiting on a promise that won't resolve but reject, here is a patch to catch the error and still pass in the `andThen` ember test helper.

```js
Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper('waitForControllerWithPromise', function(app, controllerName) {
  return new Ember.Test.promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // inform the test framework that there is an async operation in progress,
    // so it shouldn't consider the test complete
    Ember.Test.adapter.asyncStart();

    // get a handle to the promise we want to wait on
    var controller = app.__container__.lookup('controller:' + controllerName);
    var promise = controller.get('promise');

    promise.then(function(){
      // wait until the afterRender queue to resolve this promise,
      // to give any side effects of the promise resolving a chance to
      // occur and settle
      Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', null, resolve);

      // inform the test framework that this async operation is complete
      Ember.Test.adapter.asyncEnd();
    }).catch(function() {
      // when the promise is rejected, resolve it to pass in `andThen()`
      Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', null, resolve);
      Ember.Test.adapter.asyncEnd();
    });
  });
});
```