# Trigger an input's action from an acceptance test?

Tags: ember.js

I've got this in my template:

```
  {{ input
    value=model.title
    focus-out="finishEditingTitle"
    insert-newline="finishEditingTitle"
  }}
```

The action is asynchronous. I would like to test that after a user finishes editing the text field, the action is performed and the result is reflected on the page.

I tried this

```
fillIn('input', 'asdf');
keyEvent('input', 'keypress', 13);
```

But it won't trigger the action!

At the same time, doing `click('button');` on a `<button {{action "save"}}>` does trigger the action.

**How do i trigger an input's action from an acceptance test?**

A fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dapuge/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to **wait** for the UI events to complete before doing your tests.

You need to keep working with promises. If your needs were more convoluted, you would have to write custom code in your controller to make sure this happens. (For example: [Using Ember (cli) how do I get an acceptance test to wait for a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498845)).

Luckily for your case there are already helpers that take care of the asynchrony, see: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/

The actual answer, just:

```
click('.title');
fillIn('input', 'asdf');
triggerEvent('input', 'blur');
```

Note, this wouldn't work:

```
//triggerEvent('input', 'blur');
Ember.$('<input>').blur();
```

Comment: Yay, this works for `focus-out="someAction"` and resolves my issue. But what if i had a different action for `insert-newline="anotherAction"`? How do i trigger that?

Comment: Trigger both actions consecutively. If they have completely different side effects, then its time to write 2 acceptance tests.

Comment: The question is how yo trigger the `insert-newline` action, even in a separate test.

Comment: keyEvent(selector, type, keyCode) http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/

Comment: Yeah, it should work and it doesn't :( I don't know why, if I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: looks like using `keydown` and `keyup` work, but `keypress` does not. [See the exact code here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37868689/260491)  cc: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov

Answer (score 3):

As defined here: 
http://snipplr.com/view/53641/jquery-simulate-keypress-trigger/

Use keyup instead of keypress:

```
fillIn('input', 'asdf');
keyEvent('input', 'keyup', 13);
```

Comment: Ember has a test helper library now as well.  The answer is basically the same however:

```
import { triggerKeyEvent } from '@ember/test-helpers';
// ...
triggerKeyEvent('input', 'keyup', 13);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `action='save'` in your input, if you remove it, you don't have to wait for the click event either. You already have a bind there, take advantage of that.

```
{{input value=model.bar}}

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  // trigger whenever the input's value changes
  _save: function() {
    Ember.Logger.debug('IndexController: save');
      this.get('model').save();
  }.observes('model.bar'),

  actions: {
    // trigger the action from other DOM elements
    save: function() {
      this._save();
    }
  }
});
```

I edited your example, all tests pass now:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baqoguyapa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you @givanse, this is awesome! Why do we need a `.observes('model.bar')` on the action when we already got that on the method that the action is calling?

Comment: Hey @givanse, in my app the input is defined like this: `{{input value=model.bar focus-out="finishEditingTitle" insert-newline="finishEditingTitle"}}`. I don't think it's possible to use your suggestion for my situation. :( What do you think?

Comment: We don't need the observer in the action handler, it was a typo, I updated the answer.

Comment: Do you have another fiddle? I don't see how `focus-out` and `insert-newline` have an impact on the acceptance test, my guess is that those are only events that modify the appearance of the input.

Comment: I don't want to send a request to backend on every keypress. I want to save the request only after the user finishes editing. Here's the fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dapuge/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This might still be useful for others, so I'm adding another answer.

Comment: how do you trigger a select input?

Comment: I tried $('#fooSelect').trigger({type:'mouseup', which:1})` and $('#fooSelect').trigger({type:'click'})`