# How to trigger an `input` field's `newline` action in an Ember.js acceptance test?

Tags: testing, ember.js, acceptance-testing

I had thought that `keyEvent('.my input', 'keypress', 13);` would trigger the input's `newline` action, but it doesn't seem to.

It seems others have had [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586314/trigger-an-inputs-action-from-an-acceptance-test#comment45528478_28596428)

Is there any other/better way to trigger the newline action from my acceptance test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like triggering a `keydown` then a `keyup` event (instead of a `keypress`) does the trick:

```
keyEvent('.my input', 'keydown', 13);
keyEvent('.my input', 'keyup', 13);
```