# Ember -- component integration async tests aren't waiting until async calls are returned

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-testing

I'm having a hard time testing async functionality in component integration tests. Input kicks off an async call to an endpoint, and when it returns, I send an action. I'm trying to test that the action sends the correct data.

I've tried putting my assertion in the `wait()` helper, but the assertion gets hit before the (dependent upon async) action is called.

Here's a twiddle showing that problem: https://ember-twiddle.com/79f9a80c639b642e538803ac64a1cf9d?openFiles=tests.integration.components.test-comp-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.test-comp.hbs

How can I correctly code my async component integration tests?

Comment: Are you really calling `setTimeout` like that in your component?

Comment: No, that's just a stand-in for a real ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that fails your test:

1. Firstly, never make use of `setTimeout` (`window.setTimeout`) to schedule some future work with Ember. Make use the Ember way of doing it; I mean `Ember.run.later`. For the same thing that happened to me with acceptance tests; please see the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547516/ember-simple-auth-acceptance-tests-and-waiting-for-async-actions/43601736) and look through comments on the answer. The reason is that; Ember's test helpers really cannot handle `setTimeout` as we expect it.
2. You have a problem within the test itself; in the action handler you have written in test you need to change the `name` attribute instead of returning a promise.

Anyway please see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c4e5e4366b28b444bd192125f35b5a27?openFiles=tests.integration.components.test-comp-test.js%2C&route=%2Ftest-promise-route) I have updated. Testing in general with Ember is kind of a pain; since I believe there is not a proper comprehensive documentation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the updated twiddle, that's great that it works with ember.run.later. My setTimeout in that case is just a placeholder for an ajax call. If I were to have an ajax call there instead of a settimeout, what would I need to change?

Comment: It will work for `Ember.$.ajax` I suppose. See the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a7d82abc565a0be25c8be0a7cb8ec10d?openFiles=routes.simple-ajax-route.js%2C&route=%2Ftest-promise-route)'s `simple-ajax-route` acceptance test. Although this is an acceptance test; nothing will change for an integration test hopefully :)